# Is there a way to get page X and page Y with click event when trigger it manually

Tags: jquery

I make a button with on click function. when I click on it I got page X and page Y but when I try to click the button by using button.trigger('click') in this page X and Page Y is not coming.

```js
$('#click-me').click(function(e) {

  console.log('pageY', e.pageY);
  console.log('pageX', e.pageX);
});

setTimeout(function() {
  $('#click-me').trigger('click');
}, 1000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

 <button id="click-me">Click Me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're not passing any event to `click` (`e` does not exist). Triggering `click` does not simulate an event, it just calls the function.

Comment: why will you need the mouse position if you trigger the click via javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Well it makes sense, since there is no mouse involved in a manually triggered event.  You would need to keep track of the last mouse position (by listening to mouse move event) and trigger the event like so: https://jsfiddle.net/ghnpjL4c/1/

```
$(function(){
    var lastX = 0;
    var lastY = 0;

  $('#clickMe').on('click', function(e){
    console.log("PageX " + e.pageX);
    console.log("PageY " + e.pageY);
  });

  $(document).on('mousemove', function(e){
    lastX = e.pageX;
    lastY = e.pageY;
  });

  setTimeout(function(){
    var e = $.Event('click');
    e.pageX = lastX;
    e.pageY = lastY;
    $('#clickMe').trigger(e);
  }, 3000);
})
```